# Https Load Balancer for backend bucket, but not exposed to internet

Tags: https, cloud-storage, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

-Before trying internal https LB, I have already tested External HTTPS LB exposed directly to internet for backend bucket.

In this case, I have created all necessary resources in GCP

`(google_compute_global_forwarding_rule, google_compute_target_https_proxy, google_compute_global_address, google_dns_managed_zone, google_dns_record_set, google_compute_ssl_certificate, google_compute_url_map, google_compute_backend_bucket, google_storage_bucket with storage_class "MULTI_REGIONAL")`

I have activated public access for bucket.

Finally, the static website for bucket is exposed directly to internet and works correctly in this case.

**Goal**: **Static website for buckets would not be exposed directly to internet in test environments.**

-SO I have tried intenal https LB: I have created all necessary resources (google_compute_forwarding_rule, google_compute_region_target_https_proxy, google_compute_address using private DNS, google_compute_region_url_map, google_compute_backend_bucket, regional storage bucket....).

I got failure when creating the resource google_compute_region_url_map in which the default_service points to the backend bucket. The message error indicates that **there is no backend in the same region**.

The problem is with google_compute_backend_bucket which is global and not regional (There is no regional backend bucket in GCP).

I have noticed also that all samples of internal https LB in GCP are with backend service and not backend bucket.

-I have made some research about Private service connect with internal https LB (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal).
But I think it will not work also for the same reason: It must be regional and we don't have regional backend bucket.

What do you think? Have you any suggestions? Is this goal possible in GCP?